# Add Custom validation with Clientside validation

Tags: javascript, forms

Can anyone show me an example for adding custom clientside validation in drupal?
I need to add my custom validation work with client side validation. I want to make it work my custom validation with [Clientside Validation](https://drupal.org/project/clientside_validation) Module validation.

Code I have written:

```
function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
if($form_id == 'user_register_form') {
    $form['#validate'][] = '_user_register_form_validate';

    $form['account']['email_confirm'] = array(
       '#type' => 'textfield',
       '#title' => t('Re-enter e-mail'),
       '#required' => TRUE,
       '#weight' => '-3',
       '#description' => '',
     );
}
function _user_register_form_validate($form, &$form_state) {
  if($form_state['values']['mail'] != $form_state['values']['email_confirm']) {
    form_set_error('email_confirm',"E-mail address doesn't match - please try again.");  
  }
}
```

My code is working with normal page submission. What should I do make it work with Clientside Validation?

I have tried some methods that mentioned in the below link. But noting I couldn't make it work.
https://drupal.org/node/1324772

I am using Drupal 7.

Comment: You need to add js with your module for client side validation.

Comment: Can you show me an example?

Comment: @ARUN have you looked for "examples for developers" on Drupal.org?